# Writing the Assembly version to a string and saving this into a textfile C#

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to write the assembly version to a textfile for use with an autoupdater program.
This is what I have for getting the current assembly version to a string.

```
// Get assembly info to string
    string assemblyVersion = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("MainApplication.exe").Version.ToString();
```

This is then being written to a textfile using filestream.

```
private void SaveVersion()
    {
        // creating filestream that can write a file
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("Version.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        // if we don't have permission to write we exit function
        if (!fs.CanWrite)
            return;

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(assemblyVersion);
        // writing whole buffer array
        fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        // closing filestream
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

However for some reason the Version.txt file is never being populated.

What am I missing here. Thanks.

Comment: Did you debug code? Perhaps, it doesn't reach the line with saving.

Comment: And make your life easier with [File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext)

Comment: I doubt you have permission to write to the program files directory.  Gotta write it to program data folder or somewhere the user has access to.

Comment: Just a side note, but `CanWrite` doesn't check permissions, only that the stream is open and in a writable mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single line of code

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("Version.txt", assemblyVersion);
```